# Jquery unable to set the values in option list

Tags: jquery, json

Further to my [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528445/getting-inconsistent-output-on-iterating-over-json) 
Here is it's fiddle, but not working my javascript there.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22x8R/)
I'hv changed my data to :

```
json.array = {
    F_02_0010: {
        0: "-------",
        1: "20億円以上",
        2: "14億円以上20億円未満",
        3: "7億円以上14億円未満",
        4: "7000万円以上7億円未満",
        5: "7000万円未満"
    },
    F_02_0110: {
        0: "-------",
        1: "10億円以上",
        2: "7億円以上10億円未満",
        3: "4億円以上7億円未満",
        4: "4000万円以上4億円未満",
        5: "4000万円未満"
    },
    F_02_0210: {
        0: "-------",
        1: "10億円以上",
        2: "7億円以上10億円未満",
        3: "4億円以上7億円未満",
        4: "5000万円以上4億円未満",
        5: "5000万円未満"
    },
    "default": {
        0: "-------"
    }
};

var evaluate_result = function(val){
    if (val == 1){
        set_options_list($(".asset"), json.array.F_02_0010);
    }else if (val == 2){
        set_options_list($(".asset"), json.array.F_02_0110);
    }else if (val == 3){
        set_options_list($(".asset"), json.array.F_02_0210);
    }else{
        set_options_list($(".asset"), json.array.default);
    }
}
```

And here problem is in my function :

I'm getting following correct console result for all the json but options are displaying only for  this json `json.array.F_02_0010`

```
var set_options_list = function(selctelm, jsonarray){
    $(selctelm).empty();
    for ( key in jsonarray){
        var val = jsonarray[key];
        // I'm getting following correct values for all above json 
        console.log(key, val, selctelm);
        //But this code is working only for first json i.e. json.array.F_02_0010
        $(selctelm).append(
                $("<option></option>").text(val).val(key)
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: Make a fiddle for this, also working only for first json explain

Comment: I don't know how to make a fiddle, let me check

Comment: in here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: looks like working in fiddle

Comment: @Rex: Nope, not working for me On change of first option list I'm getting : `Uncaught ReferenceError: update_data_by_selection is not defined`

Comment: check this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/22x8R/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the `on change of your select list`

```
$(".form-largeItem").change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == 1){
        set_options_list($(".asset"), json.array.F_02_0010);
    }else if (val == 2){
        set_options_list($(".asset"), json.array.F_02_0110);
    }else if (val == 3){
        set_options_list($(".asset"), json.array.F_02_0210);
    }else{
        set_options_list($(".asset"), json.array.default);
    }
});
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/22x8R/5/)

Comment: @Thanks: Working now.